# Parent Process Waiting for Child to Finish in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 /* 80 chars per line, per command, should be enough. */

/**
 * setup() reads in the next command line, separating it into distinct tokens
 * using whitespace as delimiters. It also sets the args parameter as a 
 * null-terminated string.
 */

void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[],int *background)
{
    int length, /* Number  of characters in the command line */
        i,      /* Loop index for inputBuffer array */
        start,  /* Index where beginning of next command parameter is */
        ct;     /* Index of where to place the next parameter into args[] */

    ct = 0;

    /* Read what the user enters on the command line */
    length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, MAX_LINE);  

    start = -1;
    if (length == 0)
        exit(0);            /* ^d was entered, end of user command stream */
    if (length < 0){
        perror("error reading command");
    exit(-1);           /* terminate with error code of -1 */
    }

    /* Examine every character in the inputBuffer */
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        switch (inputBuffer[i]){
        case ' ':
        case '\t' :               /* argument separators */
            if(start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];    /* set up pointer */
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0'; /* add a null char; make a C string */
            start = -1;
            break;

        case '\n':                 /* should be the final char examined */
            if (start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];     
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            args[ct] = NULL; /* no more arguments to this command */
            break;

        case '&':
            *background = 1;
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            break;

        default :             /* some other character */
            if (start == -1)
                start = i;
    } 
    }    
    args[ct] = NULL; /* just in case the input line was > 80 */
} 

int main(void)
{
    char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE]; /* Buffer to hold the command entered */
    int background;             /* Equals 1 if a command is followed by '&' */
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];/* Command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */


    while (1){            /* program terminates normally inside setup */
    background = 0;
    printf("CSE2431Sh->");
        fflush(0);
        setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);       /* get next command */

    /* the steps are:
     (1) fork a child process using fork()
     (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
     (3) if background == 0, the parent will wait, 
        otherwise returns to the setup() function. */

          /* MY CODE HERE */
          pid_t pid;

        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0)
        {
                execvp(args[0],args);
                /* If execvp returns, it must have failed. */

                printf("Fork Failed\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                if(&background == 0)
                {
                        while( wait(&background) != pid)
                        {/* Do nothing, waiting */}
                }
                else
                {
                        setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);
                }
       }
   }
}
```

I am trying to fork a child process, have the child invoke execvp() and have the parent wait while in the background. My error is coming from the wait portion of the code with the parent. Everything above where it says my code here was given and should not be edited

Comment: Your `if(&background == 0)` will always fail since the address of `background` is not `0`.

Comment: As a side note, there's no such thing as exiting with a negative status code on *nix. Generally it's the unsigned value of the least 8 bits that are used (not sure if this is universal), so exiting with -1 would really return 255.

Comment: If execv fails, why do you print "fork failed" to the wrong stream?  Try `perror( "execvp" )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'Fork failed' message should be 'Exec failed' (the fork worked; the exec didn't).  You should also have a separate 'fork failed' error report, but you're missing that at the moment. And error messages should be written to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

The `wait()` loop condition should be:

```
int corpse;
int status;
while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1 && corpse != pid)
    ;
```

While debugging, print the information from the `wait()` on each iteration.  Note that `waitpid()` allows you to wait if there is a corpse to collect, but to return if there are no dead children to be mourned.

All of that is only relevant after you've dealt with the warning you should have been getting from the compiler.  If you aren't getting warnings about `if (&background == 0)` being always false, you need to turn up the compiler warning level. If you're using GCC, `gcc -Wall` is a good start, `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes` is better.  And fix the warnings from the compiler.

Comment: I get the following error from wait(&status) shell.c: In function âint main()â:
shell.c:100: error: no matching function for call to âwait::wait(int*)â
/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h:68: note: candidates are: wait::wait()
/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h:68: note:                 wait::wait(const wait&)

Comment: Well, (a) you should be compiling with a C compiler and not a C++ compiler (or you should retag your question) and (b) you should be using `#include <sys/wait.h>` (see [`wait()` and `waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html)).  One of the advantages of the `-W*-prototypes` options is that you get warnings when you don't have a prototype in scope for a function before you call it.

Comment: My mistake with using the wrong compiler. It's habit. But nice call with using #include <sys/wait.h>. Fixed everything. I made the assumption it was already there an didn't check. Eveything works now. Big help!

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> if(&background == 0)
>    ^
> ```

That line doesn't make much sense. You're comparing the address when you likely want to compare the actual stored value, i.e. you probably want **to drop the `&`**.

Otherwise that test will never be true, that is the address of the variable `background` will never be 0.